# Grunt - plugin folder disapper after build dist

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, yeoman, bower

I'm new to Yeoman, Grunt and Bower and of course I have some trouble when building a distribution.

I used Yeoman to scaffold a webapp, built the code, added an external plugin (not through bower, there was no package for that plugin, so I just copied the plugin folder and added the references in my index.html)

When running grunt serve everything works fine, the first time I built the distribution with

```
grunt
```

I had back a lot of jshint errors about that external plugin (missing semicolons etc...small things), so I just had to run

```
grunt --force
```

to have my dist built.

In the dist folder, the external plugin folder and files were missing, so in the build process that folder was removed (but the index.html file had all the references to the files).

So with

```
grunt serve:dist
```

I had my dist on the browser, but without the plugin. At this point I copied the plugin folder in the correct spot of the dist folder, reloaded the page, and the plugin was working. Then killed the process, and I run again

```
grunt serve:dist
```

After this command, the plugin folder (that I manually copied) just disappeared, so I realize that the copy and paste is not the right way to make things working.

How can I tell grunt (or bower) to leave that folder (inside the js folder) in the same spot, not try to compress the files inside, ignore js validation with jshint, and not to remove it?

What if I want to add a new folder (called for example jsons) in the root folder? When building a distribution will be removed too? Is there a spot where I can tell grunt what folder to include/ignore?

Thanks

---- EDIT ----

This is my "copy" task in Gruntfile.js

```
copy: {
  dist: {
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      dot: true,
      cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
      dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
      src: [
        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
        '{,*/}*.html',
        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
      ]
    }, {
      src: 'node_modules/apache-server-configs/dist/.htaccess',
      dest: '<%= config.dist %>/.htaccess'
    }]
  },
  styles: {
    expand: true,
    dot: true,
    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
    dest: '.tmp/styles/',
    src: '{,*/}*.css'
  }
}
```

Comment: dist folder is rebuilt from scratch everytime you run `grunt serve:dist` (or `grunt dist`). I advise you to read http://gruntjs.com/getting-started ... (and avoid running grunt with `--force`, if not only temporarily...)

Comment: Yes, I experienced that... but how can I include that folder in the built dist?

Comment: See my answer, as an exaple (hope it can be of any help for you...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This in an extract of a 'production' `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  copy: {
    dist: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        src: [
          //'*.{ico,png,txt}',
          '*.{txt}',
          '.htaccess',
          '*.html',
          '*.appcache',
          'views/{,*/}*.html',
          'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
          'icons/**/*.{ico,png}',
          'scripts/i18n/{,*/}*.js',
          'i18n/{,*/}*.json',
        ]
      }, {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '.tmp/images',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
        src: ['generated/*']
      }, {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
        src: 'fonts/*',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      }, {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/open-sans-fontface',
        src: 'fonts/**/*',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
      }, {
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome',
        src: 'fonts/*',
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      }]
    },
  },

  ...

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    ...
    'copy:dist',
    ...
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'build',
  ]);

};
```

**Please**, read http://gruntjs.com/getting-started (it's a five minutes task... :-).

Comment: Yes, you are right about the doc, I just cannot find the right spot to look at. Why it is deleting the folder? I assume the first one in your example is the copy of the app folder into dist folder, there is an expand: true, so I assume it copies everything inside that folder (and do stuff like minifying etc...), I have to manually add the folder inside src: ?
Thanks for your help!
PS: I updated my answer with the same extract as yours of my Gruntfile.js